# Remove time, date, and package name from System.out.print in Android Studio logcat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I want to remove the following sort of text

> *"06-11 14:36:59.814    3951-4564/example.myapplication I/System.out﹕"*

from my system.out.prints in my app.

How can I accomplish this?? I am using android studio

Comment: I think the solution here should be to use the proper `Log` class because 1) that's how print to the logcat in Android and 2) it's less to type

Answer (score 61):

## Android Studio *2.2*

Not sure which version made this available but 2.2 has it...

[image: logcat settings control]

[image: default with date time package suggestions for dinner]

[image: what we all generally want: TAG and our debug statement]

Just found this myself.  So happy.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I can't seem to find this in Android Studio 3.2

Comment: It works for my Andriod Studio 4.1.1. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Since Android Studio Flamingo / Giraffe, in your LogCat select the option "Configure LogCat Formatting Options" then "Modify Views"

[image]

Here you can enable/disable the timestamp

[image]

Comment: After Invalidate Cache this method worked perfectly 